# multiple window onclick event in one page

Tags: javascript, jquery

For some reason, I need two windows onclick event on one page

```
window.onclick = function(event) {
    alert("abc") 
}

window.onclick = function(event) {
    console.log("abc");
}
```

but only the second one run.
Any idea how I can make both works.

Comment: why you need that?

Comment: Use `addEventListener`

Comment: Use the `jquery` you already tagged this with for event handling …?

Comment: Need to know the scenario's why you need like that. So that we can give you the suggestion how to handle that.

Comment: Why you don't run both console.log and alert under one click function!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are overwriting `window.onclick` so only the latter will run. You should use [addEventListener](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_addeventlistener.asp) instead if you want to use vanilla JS.

```
window.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    alert("abc") 
});

window.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    console.log("abc");
});
```

If you are using jquery, then you can use jQuerys [.click](https://api.jquery.com/click/).

```
$(window).click(function(event) {
    alert("abc") 
});

$(window).click(function(event) {
    console.log("abc");
});
```

Comment: jQuery example have syntax error so the right way is $(window).click

Comment: I cannot request new edit but I see that the example is changed. Anyway, the window should be without single quotation marks. I tried with them but it didn't work. So $(window) without quotation marks worked.

Answer (score 2):

What you are doing is equivalent to

```
var a = 1;
var a = 2;
```

And then ask to have two variables `a`.

It is simply impossible, there can only be one function named `onclick` in your example.

Answer (score 0):

This is not correct approach, but if you have to, you can do it like this using jQuery:

```
  $("#myButton").click(function() {
    alert(1);
  });

  $("#myButton").click(function() {
    alert(2);
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (!event.target.matches("")) {}


  if (!event.target.matches("")) {}

}
```

Comment: You should give an explanation why you think this solves the problem and maybe tell what is wrong in the original code.